# How to make Firefox download to Downloads folder even when "Open with xxx" is selected?

Tags: gnome, firefox, directory, downloads

I have recently noticed that when downloading something with Firefox, if I select the option "Open with xxx" instead of just the "Save file" option, the file is then downloaded to `/tmp` and opened with whatever program I have selected:

[image: Download prompt Firefox]

However I would like for this to change, so how can I make it so that the "Open with xxx" also downloads the file to my `~/Downloads` folder (as well as opening it then of course with whatever I have selected, everything should be the same as before except for the download location)?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and Firefox 42.

Comment: I think this could be accomplished if all of us ask Mozilla to integrate it in the next update . I'm sure it's related to Firefox entirely and not Ubuntu but I'm not flagging it as off-topic because it is something that a lot of people are looking for.

Comment: @adeen-s: How do we ask Mozilla? And is there no way for the system to just detect that Firefox is downloading a file there and when the download is complete to just move it to the `~/Downloads` folder?

Comment: You want something like "Save And Open" ? Maybe I can write a script for that. Give me some time .

Comment: [this](https://input.mozilla.org/en-US/feedback/firefox?)is how we ask Mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is better done by some kind of firefox add-on. Below is a (really bad) hack that works. (For PDF files but you can modify to work with any kind of downloaded file type).

```
#!/bin/bash
fn=$(find /tmp -type f -cmin -1 | head -1)
evince "$fn" #Use `evince` if you are dealing with PDFs. Change program for other file types!
mv "$fn" ~/Downloads
```

save this script and make it executable. In `about:preferences#applications` of firefox, select PDF and associate the above script with PDF file type.

Now whenever you click on PDF files, it should download and open up in the Document Viewer. On closing it, the file will be saved to `~/Downloads`.

You can edit the script and change the program (for eg: `file-roller` to open archives) for different file types and tell firefox to associate these scripts with their file types.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a script to run firefox and change an advanced setting inside firefox.

First the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp_folder='/home/your_user_name/Downloads/firefox'
export TMP=$tmp_folder
export TEMP=$tmp_folder
mkdir $tmp_folder
firefox
```

This will create a special directory inside Downloads called firefox where all tmp downloads will go

Now inside firefox open the advanced settings by typing `about:config` in a window. Search for a boolean or create a new one called `browser.helperApps.deleteTempFileOnExit` and set it to false

Now when you run firefox using your script you get the desired results, i.e. all opened files are saved inside Downloads/firefox and will not be deleted. You can change the directory to Downloads of course as well.

Comment: Are there any other temporary files other than what I choose to download that will be kept when they would have been deleted before? Or does this only refer to when I download something in this way

Comment: This will put also the cache under Downloads.

Comment: Right, so I don't think that this is necessarily a good way to do it then, I don't want all tmp files for Firefox to be downloaded there, I *only*  want those that I have asked it to download by click on a download button on a website. Not the cache etc, those aren't the kind of tmp downloads that I mean and I don't want them to go to a new location so I am sorry but this answer will not do, it needs to be done in a more clean way.

Comment: And if it also means that disabling the option to remove tmp files on exit will also stop other temporary files such as the cache being deleted, then that could cause a security issue for me, and also a nuisance in some other ways depending on what files are kept that usually wouldn't be.

Comment: I don't think it puts the cache files there, and it should only prevent files from being deleted that were opened by other programs. Try it for a day of browsing and you will know what's left in that directory.